# Using sim() with lmer()

Tags: r, variance, sim-card, lme4

I have run two multilevel logistic regressions using the same predictors, but on two different responses:

```
fruitMLM <- lmer(InsuffFruit ~ Income + HDI + Income:HDI + (1 + Income | Country),family=binomial(link="logit"))  
fuelMLM <- lmer(Pollution ~ Income + HDI + Income:HDI + (1 + Income | Country),family=binomial(link="logit"))
```

`Income` is discrete with values `c(-2,-1,0,1,2)`, `HDI` is continuous between 0 and 1, `Country` is categorical, and the responses are both 1/0.

To plot confidence bands I run a simulation using the sim() function from the arm package:

```
sim(fruitMLM,100)  
sim(fuelMLM,100)
```

The first one computes fine.  The second one returns the following error:

```
Error in mvnorm(n.sims, bhat[j,], V.beta) :  
  'Sigma' is not positive definite
```

I actually am doing this with 8 different responses.  Six of them worked fine and two of them returned this error.

Does anyone know how to rectify this?

Comment: What version of `arm`?  I know this was a problem in an earlier version (see point 6 here: http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~cook/movabletype/archives/2007/09/recent_changes.html).

Comment: It is also easier to debug a problem if you can provide some sample data to reproduce it.

Comment: Shane,
Sorry for the delay, I didn't realize I was getting comments.

The people I was building the models for dealt w/o the sims for some of the models.

The arm I used may have been out of date.  I think I tried the simulations again recently with a new install of arm and it worked.  But I'll most likely be revisiting it again soon and will see from there.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you see if the error message is correct, i.e., check "by hand" whether the covariance matrix from the failing model is actually positive semi-definite? I'm not sure, but I imagine there are some checks you could perform - maybe there's something here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I'm going to be revisiting the problem soon, so I'l try that out.

Sorry for my delay, I didn't realize I was getting replies.